# Loops in array with split using Perl

Tags: perl

Using `split` with values in an array.

```
($field[1],
$field[2],
$field[3],
$field[4],
$field[5]) = split(",", $line);
```

I read in a file.

Using `split`, take each value after the delimiter `,` using an array.

There are five files on each line, so as you can imagine, I want to take in 
one line per loop iteration.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Why are you writing a [CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) from scratch?

Comment: @Quentin maybe he can't install modules. Or it is painful. But you are right, it is better to load modules or use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/)

Comment: @loldop, often people think they "can't install modules", but it is almost always an artificial constraint.  There are many ways of using modules in restricted environments.  This has often been discussed, but here is one good example: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828

Comment: @dan1111 yes, i know how to install modules. But sometimes i need fast solution. Also, i don't want to stuck with installation modules on Mac, for example. And i write my own small helpful scripts. But on my home linux mint there are enough modules.

Comment: What is your problem? What is wrong with what you have written?

Comment: @loldop, fair enough.  I personally think that processing a basic CSV file is easy enough that a module isn't necessarily needed.  I just see the "I can't install modules" objection a lot and think it needs to be answered.

Comment: Your split operation seems a little verbose, I would use `@field[1..5] = split(',',$line)` or just `@field = split(',',$line)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
while (<$fh>){
  my @tmp;
  @tmp = split(/,/,$line);
  warn "Less than 5 items on a line: $line\n" if scalar(@tmp) != 5;

}
```

or you could use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to read the file

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($line = < F >)
 {
 @clpData= split(/,/, $line);

 print "@clpData[9]\n";
 }
```